# Move files from fileshare to document library but keeping modifed date, modified by CSOM Powershell

Tags: powershell, csom, document-migration

I am wanting to do a migration where I move files from a fileshare to a document library in office 365. This needs to be done in CSOM powershell and needs to keep all of the modified dates, modified by etc.